# I have a dataframe with two columns, "major one" and "major two". How can I make a new column "majors"?

Tags: python, pandas

For example, currently my data looks like (mockup):

In:

```
print(pandas.pivot_table(dataframe,values='id',index=['major_one','major_two'],columns='status',aggfunc='count',fill_value=fill_character),'\n')
```

Out:

```
status               Registered  Withdrawn
major_one major_two                       
ENGL      BIOL                3          0
          FILM               10          0
BIOL      FILM                4          0
          ENGL                7          1
```

I want it to look like:

```
status  Registered  Withdrawn
majors                       
ENGL           27          1
BIOL            3          0
FILM           14          0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [melting](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) your original dataframe before pivoting so that you have a single "majors" column and THEN pivot on the majors column as your index.

e.g.

```
# pd.melt(df, value_vars = ["major_one", "major_two"], var_name = "major")
# READ EDIT INSTEAD
```

Read the docs accordingly, the snippet above is based off what I imagine your input data looks like, but you haven't posted a sample at all.

EDIT:

```
pd.melt(df, value_vars = ['major_one', 'major_two'], var_name = 'major_number', value_name = "major", id_vars = ['id', 'status'])
```

Comment: Pivoting on the new majors column fails with "KeyError: 'majors'."

Comment: The input data is a CSV of student records. So 'id', 'status,' 'major_one', and 'major_two' are all headers.

Comment: That's because the command above will make a new column called "major", not "majors".  Sorry, typo on my part, pivot on "major".

Comment: I updated the one-liner you probably want.  That will give you a dataframe, and from there, you'll want to save it to a new dataframe and call pivot on "major" as the index, "status" as the columns, and "count" as your aggfunc.

Comment: No, I caught that, unfortunately it still fails with 'keyerror: major"

Comment: Hmm. What if I have various other variables in the original dataframe that I also want to keep manipulating? I only posted the relevant parts of my code.

Comment: Add those columns to the list of column names in the `id_vars` keyword.  The [docs on pd.melt](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) should be pretty helpful.

Comment: You did it! Thank you!

Comment: No problem -- Feel free to accept the answer if it was helpful!